# Return entire collection from MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

using the official mongo / c# drivers - what is the best way of returning an entire collection, and what is the best way of storing the data? I've seen some examples of iterating over a collection and returning a particular value, like this:

```
var collection = db.getCollection("users").findAll();
foreach (var value in collection){
     value = collection["key"];
     ...
}
```

but what if I don't know the key names - and I just want to return the collection?

Comment: var keys = value .Keys.ToArray(); foreach(var key in keys){value = collecion[key];}

Comment: What I mean is, what is the most appropriate mechanism for getting all of the documents and storing them. The next part of the equation is what is the best data structure to store this in... The code wasn't validated - just an example, but the C# should look mostly like that.

Comment: There is no reasonable way of storing an entire collection - I have seen some with multiple TBs.

Comment: both very useful comments - thanks chaps!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to know the key names when returning a collection.

```
 public static void ReadCollectionDataUsingBson(string collectionName, string databaseName)
    {
        MongoDatabase database = CreateDatabase(databaseName);

        MongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName);
        foreach (BsonDocument document in collection.FindAll())
        {
            foreach (string name in document.Names)
            {
                BsonElement element = document.GetElement(name);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", name, element.Value);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Note: CreateDatabase() function is user defined, so i have just shown you the required code over here.